# Magento 2 automatically appends form key at the end of my ajax call

Tags: magento2, ajax, rest-api

I am trying to use jquery to perform ajax call to a magento rest api from a custom backend (admin) module. For some reason, every time I perform ajax call, the query parameter `isAjax=true` automatically gets appended to the url, and `&form_key=mJRSj3FScbiIKWsl` automatically gets appended to my request payload. Is there any way I can prevent this?

Comment: The `form_key` param needed to prevent [csrf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). The `isAjax` in most cases used to determine type of content for response.

Answer (score 12):

Magento 2 adds the form key and the `isAjax` by using jQuery's `beforeSend` handler. to remove it override the `beforeSend` handler with and empty function for example. 
You can also put the `form_key` in the url to prevent csrf:

```
echo $block->getUrl('destination/path/index', ['form_key' => $block->getFormKey()]);
```

Here is an example to send JSON data:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: destinationUrl,
    method: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    showLoader: true,
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        //Empty to remove magento's default handler
    }
}).done(function (resp) {
    //handle success scenario
}).fail(function (resp) {
    //handle failure scenario
});
```

Comment: +1 for using `done` rather than `success`, I wasn't aware of that. More info here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840257/jquery-ajax-handling-continue-responses-success-vs-done